# AngularJS - Why objects in Services trigger $digest loops and assignment values don't?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been fiddling with AngularJS services for quite some time and I'm opposed with a problem regarding 2-way binding.

Perhaps an example might help:
I have a variable `address` in my `service`, and I want it to be populated via $http service call. But once the XHR finishes, the changes in the `address` var doesn't get cascaded to the controller - lest, I put an implicit watch on it. Moreover, the binding works when `object notation` is used on the values i.e. `address.street`.

Can you share your thoughts on this? Is this related to the `pass by reference` concept of programming?

By the way, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/8v7m4/1/) that I created to simulate my dilemma.

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe what you're seeing is the result of mixing primitive and reference assignments.

In the JSFiddle you've provided, `name` is being assigned to a primitive (i.e. string) and `address` to an object. Then, in your controller, you attempt to assign these service variables (via methods) to variables under `$scope`.

Since `name` is a primitive, `$scope.name` ends up copying the string value only, and hence never get updated even when the relevant service is called. Primitives are, after all, immutable.

On the other hand, since `address` is an object, and irrespective of whether you use object notion as you've noted, `$scope.address` copies the reference and will subsequently be notified of updates to the value.

Here's a great read that explains in detail the concepts surrounding your conundrum.

http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/

Comment: Hi miqid, I'll be reading up your provided article and will come back later if you've hit the spot with your resource. Thanks in advanced!